Stl file import problem
I try to import the stl file, but it looks like it has zero dimensions.
I tried to deal with the problem according to this topic:
cannot see the geometry of the imported stl file
But unfortunately it didn't help.
This is the site I got STL from:
https://skrimarket.com/slicer/new?printable_id=3049&printable_type=ProductComponent&product_id=1224
Can you help me?


Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Hi. The link you provided requires an account and cannot be downloaded, you also didn't provide much info we can use to diagnose the issue. We don't have much to go by making this question unanswerable. Go through the linked question which is most likely to solve your issue with one of the solutions, otherwise please edit your post with more details or a file we can look at using blend-exchange.com
